# Is there a recommended way for interaction between python and MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, interaction

What is the recommonded way to interact between python and MySQL? Currently I am using MySQLdb and I heared from Oursql. But I asked myself, if there is a more appropriate way to manage this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MySQLdb is what most people use at the lower level, but oursql is interesting too. You can use higher level mechanisms such as

- [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/)
- [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/) - note it comes with a whole web framework :)
- I'm sure you can find others, look for 'python orm'

Answer (score 0):

I personally use pymysql, but have heard a lot of people use MySQLdb. Both are very similar in the way they behave, and could easily be interchangeable. Personally, (working as a python/MySQL QA) I've yet to hear of / let alone work with OurSQL.

With that said, it honestly depends what you want to accomplish. Python has a lot of connectors, and a tons of bells and whistles to complete almost anything; (and) As such, it is important to note that it is important to always look at how popular the component is, as well as how frequently it gets updated.